# Problem with class_getInstanceSize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have my class derived from UITabBar:

```
@interface MyTabBar : UITabBar
@end

@implementation MyTabBar
@end
```

Further, in my code, I call class_getInstanceSize for my class and system UITabBar class:

```
size_t origSize = class_getInstanceSize([UITabBar class]);
size_t mySize   = class_getInstanceSize([MyTabBar class]);
```

I use iOS SDK 4.1. When I run on iPhone Simulator (iPhone 4) i get the same value for origSize and mySize. But if I run on real device with SDK 3.1.3 I get different values, 68 for origSize and 80 for mySize. How can it be?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you want to do this. You could look at the ivar layout and see if there's anything obvious...

Comment: I want to be sure, that my subclass does not add new instance variable. Maybe checking instance size is not best way to do it and maybe I will check ivar lists instead of check sizes. But I want understand how it can be, that instance's size of derived class does not equal instance of base class, if derived class does not add new ivars.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they changed the implementation of subclassing behind the scenes. You should log the return of `class` for each OS to find out if your still dealing with the same class behind the scenes. Chances are good that you are not. They may be in the process of migrating one class to another in a class cluster.